# Visual Studio 2015 / 2017 times out on connecting to Microsoft R Open (3.4.0.0) or CRAN

Tags: r, visual-studio, rtvs

Unable to connect to Microsoft R Open or CRAN R selecting either through Workspaces window in VS2015 and 2017 Community editions on Windows 10.

"Connecting to ...." dialog appears and eventually the following error appears in the interactive window.

Connecting to R Workspace failed.
Reason: Timed out while waiting for broker process to report its endpoint URI
Interactive Window is disconnected from R session.
Open Workspaces window and either select local R interpreter or try connecting to a remote machine.

Have uninstalled/reinstalled R and RTVS.
Have tested both R installations via RGUI and R Studio.

Any direction would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need VS 2017 update 3 to use R 3.4. This was only officially released   last week, so you may not have it yet. Try updating VS.

Comment: Thanks Hong. I'll investigate and apply it and see how that goes.